# How can I set my JFrame's setDefaultCloseOperation() value in NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I'm trying to learn Java so sorry if this is a stupid question, but I seem to be unable to change the default close operation on my JFrame in NetBeans.

In NetBeans I created a JFrame and implemented some controls on it using the NetBeans GUI designer.  However, I noticed that after I close the JFrame, my application would close even though I have another form that is supposed to appear afterwards.

After digging through the JFrame generated code I found:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

From research it appears that this causes the application to close when the frame is closed. I would prefer to not have this happen.  From looking around, it appears I either need to use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` or `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` in order to get the window to close but still have additional code to run.

However, I can't figure out how to get NetBeans to change this value through the designer.  I found the `defaultCloseOperation` in the Properties -> Bindings window, but every time I enter something into the text area and press enter my text disappears.  The binding has an elipsis but I can't figure out what the binding window actually does.

How can I change my `setDefaultCloseOperation()` to a new value?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you think your application should do after the Window has closed? And, more interesting, what does it do in the meantime?

Comment: The form (first that appears) is the login form, once it closes the controller either needs to close the application (if we aren't logging in) or open the main application window if we successfully logged in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Netbeans]

It is right there in the properties panel. Just make sure that the whole `JFrame` is selected. You can select your `JFrame` from **Inspector** panel.

Comment: Wow, I'm not quite sure how I actually missed that :-/

Comment: Marking this as the answer, only because I suspect that I wasn't seeing it before because I didn't have the JFrame selected

Answer (score 3):

Try to update defaultCloseOperation value from Properties -> Properties tab, not binding tab

[image: Netbean properties window]

Comment: Not quite sure how I missed that

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file with a different editor (i.e. notepad) you will realize that netbeans puts some lines in the file to make specific sections read only.

You can always remove those lines, or even edit whatever you want with another editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can always right-click on your frame, choose Customize Code and make your changes there.